# Minitest run on hanami 1.0.0 somehow corrupts data in controller

Tags: ruby, minitest, hanami

I have a controller:

```
module Web::Controllers::Quiz
  class Test
    include Web::Action
    params QuizValidation

    def show(thing)
      thing
    end

    def call(params)
      if request.get?
        unless session.has_key?(:person_data_validated) && session[:person_data_validated]
          redirect_to routes.path(:person, params[:quiz_id])
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I have a spec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../../../../apps/web/controllers/quiz/test'

describe Web::Controllers::Quiz::Test do
  let(:action) { Web::Controllers::Quiz::Test.new }
  let(:params) { Hash[person: {}, quiz_id: 1] }
  let(:repository) { QuizRepository.new }
  let(:session) { Hash.new }

  before do
    # repository things
  end

  describe 'reloading page [GET]' do
    let(:params) { Hash[person: {}, quiz_id: 1, 'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET'] }

    it 'reloads current state if person data validated' do
      session[:person_data_validated] = true

      response = action.call(params)
      # there I debug values of minitest
      action.show(params[:quiz_id]).must_equal 'test'

      response[0].must_equal 200
    end
  end
end
```

PS: I should say that `'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET'` was just a lucky guess to make it work.

Okay. When I debug values with `action.show(value)` I get exactly what is expected: `session[:person_data_validated] = true` and `params[:quiz_id] = 1`.

But when I actually run this test, it prints an error:

```
Web::Controllers::Quiz::Test::reloading page [GET]#test_0002_reloads current state if person data validated:
Hanami::Routing::InvalidRouteException: No route (path) could be generated for :person - please check given arguments
```

Okay. When I explicitly set this line in controller:

`redirect_to routes.path(:person, params[:quiz_id])`

to

`redirect_to routes.path(:person, 1)`

everything works fine.

We can omit that this line of code even shouldn't be executed because of `session[:person_data_validated]` condition.

Help me understand my blindness and overcome it. How to make it work?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to include the `params QuizValidation` file to the controller (now included) with the following validation rules:

```
module Web::Controllers::Quiz
  class QuizValidation < Web::Action::Params

    # arrays of described values
    REGIONS = ::I18n.t "web.quiz.person.regions"
    QUIZ_LANGUAGE_LEVELS = ::I18n.t "web.quiz.person.quiz_language_levels"
    LANGUAGES = ::I18n.t "languages"

    params do
      required(:person).schema do
        optional(:sex).filled(:str?, included_in?: ['male', 'female'])
        optional(:age).filled(:int?, included_in?: 1..100)
        optional(:profession).filled(:str?)
        optional(:region).filled(:str?, included_in?: REGIONS)
        optional(:residence_place).filled(:str?)
        optional(:birth_place).filled(:str?)
        optional(:nationality1).filled(:str?)
        optional(:nationality2).filled(:str?)
        optional(:spoken_languages).filled(:int?, included_in?: 1..100)
        optional(:native_language).filled(:str?, included_in?: LANGUAGES)
        optional(:communication_language).filled(:str?, included_in?: LANGUAGES)
        optional(:education_language).filled(:str?, included_in?: LANGUAGES)
        optional(:quiz_language_level).filled(:str?, included_in?: QUIZ_LANGUAGE_LEVELS)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this file commented out I don't get the error but I still go inside the `if` so that `redirect_to routes.path(:person, params[:quiz_id])` gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router param should be passed as a normal parameter and then it can be validated by the `params` rules. The session declaration is shown below.

```
let(:params) { Hash[
  person: {},
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  quiz_id: 1,
  'rack.session' => { person_data_validated: true }
]}
```